# Navigation and mapping using gmapping on drone

Tags: ros, navigation, drone, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using the [Structure Sensor](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/occipital/structure-sensor-capture-the-world-in-3d?ref=nav_search) (Depth sensor) on the Parrot AR.Drone using gmapping slam

How do I run the navigation stack and how will the maps be generated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196114/navigation-and-mapping-using-gmapping-on-drone/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping is for creating a 2-D occupancy grid map.  You need 3d representation of environment. check this [page](http://vision.in.tum.de/research/quadcopter) on mapping using quadrocopter.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-28**:
Hi

The sensor that I am using gives depth output (not color unlike MS Kinect) only and so I am using gmapping

Also I am using the [PX4 autopilot](http://pixhawk.org/platforms/multicopters/ar_drone) on the Parrot Drone

**Comment by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) on 2018-02-12**:
hey! did you ever come to a solution about this problem?